# Emit different text and sound when each of three buttons is pressed

Tags: swift, event-handling

I would like to use this same code on multiple pages of photos (to help my son recognize people). So instead of reinserting the name of each person, I created the `appearingInPhoto` (tuple or array), so I can utilize just .a .b .c, instead of having to go and rename each line of code.

Is there a way to simplify the code further, so I can just have code that checks if a button is pressed (check that `sender.currentTitle` is equal to any of the tuple values) and if yes, run this code?

```
print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.a)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.a
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.a
```

This is the full function now:

```
var appearingInPhoto = (a:"omar", b:"john", c:"thomas")

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var soundName: String? = nil
    if sender.currentTitle == appearingInPhoto.a {
        print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.a)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.a
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.a
    }else if sender.currentTitle == appearingInPhoto.b {
        print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.b)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.b
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.b
    }else if sender.currentTitle == appearingInPhoto.c {
        print("pressed \(appearingInPhoto.c)")
        label.text = appearingInPhoto.c
        soundName = appearingInPhoto.c
    }
    if let soundName = soundName {
        playSoundFile(soundName)
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data type. You want an array, not a dictionary. `var appearingInPhoto:[String] = ["omar","john","thomas"]`Then loop over it

Comment: I feel that you need a model to save all information related to the user that you will show. Also detecting the appearing person by comparing the text of the button is not considered safe. if you can describe more what you want top achieve or a screenshot of the screen that you have implanted to understand the context then we can help to improve the implementation

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified (using array):

```
var appearingInPhoto = ["omar", "john", "thomas"]

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let soundName = sender.currentTitle else {
        return
    }
    if appearingInPhoto.contains(soundName) {
        print("pressed \(soundName)")
        label.text = soundName
        playSoundFile(soundName)
    }

}
```